# GROUP BY clause on multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, database, inner-join

I need to show Class Wise attendance like this

[image]

IN DB i am have separate table (studentattendance) ,which store attendance like this

[image]

I Just Need to Show Total students Present Per Class

I try to do Query which give output like this

[image]

this is my query

```
SELECT distinct CM.ClassName ,SB.SubjectName ,(select count(studentattendance.Day1) from studentattendance where day1 = 'P') as Present, convert(varchar(10),AttendanceDate ,126)  as AttendancetimeTaken
      from studentattendance SA inner join studentmaster SM on SA.StudentID=SM.ID  join ProfessorMaster p on SA.ProfessorID =p.Id 
      join Classmaster CM on SA.ClassID = CM.ID inner join SubjectMaster SB on SA.SubjectID =SB.ID
```

I need to Group Class Wise . how can I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not having the actual tables, I tried the following modifications, please try it and reply me

```
SELECT CM.ClassName ,
SB.SubjectName , count(SA.Day1) as Present,
convert(varchar(10),AttendanceDate , 126)  as AttendancetimeTaken
from studentattendance SA 
inner join studentmaster SM on SA.StudentID=SM.ID  
join ProfessorMaster p on SA.ProfessorID =p.Id 
join Classmaster CM on SA.ClassID = CM.ID 
inner join SubjectMaster SB on SA.SubjectID =SB.ID
where SA.day1 = 'P'
group by CM.ClassName, SB.SubjectName, AttendanceDate
```

Comment: Error :The multi-part identifier "studentattendance.Day1" could not be bound. but table and columns are present

Comment: Yes ...i think it is something what I expected ..thanks

Comment: Can we do it for other 2 More column like Absent and Total .. i trying to do union for 2 other column but not happening ... do we need to do it in subquery ???

Comment: You need to do it by using Common Table Expression